# How to implement a Color Matrix Filter in a GLSL shader

Tags: glsl, shader, colormatrix, colormatrixfilter

I would like to implement a Color Matrix Filter in a GLSL shader but couldn't find any documentation regarding this matter. I'm totaly new to the world of shaders (never coded one myself) so please forgive me if my explanation/vocabulary doesn't make mush sense.

**Informations I could gather so far**:

- A color matrix is composed of 5 columns (RGBA + offset) and 4 rows

[image]

The values in the first four columns are *multiplied* with the source red, green, blue, and alpha values respectively. The fifth column value is *added* (offset)

- I believe the *largest* matrices in GLSL are 4×4 `mat4` matrices (excluding the 'offset' column)
- The only `mat4` I've seen implemented in a shader looks like this:

> ```
> colorMatrix = (GPUMatrix4x4){{0.3588, 0.7044, 0.1368, 0.0},
>                              {0.2990, 0.5870, 0.1140, 0.0},
>                              {0.2392, 0.4696, 0.0912 ,0.0},
>                              {0,0,0,1.0}
>               };
> ```

**Question**:

- How can implement one ? As stated above I've never coded a GLSL shader before and unfortunately I'm unable to provide an MCVE. I would love to see an example so I can learn from it.

Thank you

EDIT:

I'm working with Processing and this is the only example I've found of vertex and fragment shaders for color rendering:

**colorvert.glsl:**

```
uniform mat4 transform;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
  gl_Position = transform * position;
  vertColor = color;
}
```

**colorfrag.glsl:**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

varying vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vertColor;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters I would try :

**Vertex:**

```cpp
#version 410 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_vertex;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 in_color;
out vec4 color;
void main()
    {
    const mat4x4 m=mat4x4               // RGBA matrix
        (
        0.3588, 0.7044, 0.1368, 0.0,
        0.2990, 0.5870, 0.1140, 0.0,
        0.2392, 0.4696, 0.0912 ,0.0,
        0.0   , 0.0   , 0.0    ,1.0
        );
    const vec4 o=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); // offset

       color    = (m * in_color) + o;   // transformation
    gl_Position = vec4(in_vertex,1.0);
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```cpp
#version 410 core
in vec4 color;
out vec4 out_color;
void main()
    {
    out_color=color;
    }
```

Just change the `#version`, layout and input attributes/uniforms to meet your needs (currently it use default **nVidia** attribute locations for fixed pipeline)

Now to convert image for example just render textured quad on `<-1,+1>`  vertex coordinate `x,y` range.

If your matrices or colors change inside fragment (for example as a result of some proceduraly generated stuff) than just move the transformation to fragment shader instead.

You can also change the `const` to `uniform` (and move it above `main`) so you can pass custom parameters on the run ...

In case you need a **GLSL** start example see:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

Comment: Very clear and comprehensive answer ! Unfortunately it didn't work for me (I'm working with Processing, question has been edited). 1. I don't see any changes in colors when messing with the color matrix. 2. I've tried to move the transformation to the fragment shader but I got mutliple errors "Use of undeclared identifier" ('m', 'in_color', 'o'). I then specified in the fragment shader "uniform vec4 in_color; uniform mat4x4 m; uniform vec4 o" but still get a "Left-hand-side of assignment must not be read-only" error.

Comment: @solub try to set the `gl_Position` as the last line of Vertex shader code as the GL implementation used could optimized out all the code after it. To make it work You also should change your line `vertColor = color;` to `vertColor = (m*color)+o;`. When you use uniforms you can not declare the values in shader instead you need to pass them from CPU side code.  If your shader contain errors than fixed pipeline is used instead so check shader logs. I do not use processing so I can not help with the CPU side code.